# AngularJs data retrieval from $resource

Tags: angularjs, callback

I have a service that gives

```
services.factory('proService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
        getValue: function (context_params) {
            var Pro = $resource('pro');
            return Pro.get({user_id: context_params.userId, course_id: context_params.cKey, activity_id: context_params.activityId});
        }
    };
}]);
```

---

My controller code. But i just get it as a promise. I need to write a call back to get the proficiency value.

```
$scope.getPro = function () {
        $scope.pro = proService.getValue({userId: $scope.userId, courseKey: $scope.courseKey, activityId: $scope.activityId});
        $scope.pro.rating = 5 * Math.round(($scope.pro.pro * 10)/5);
        console.log($scope.pro);
    };
```

---

$scope.pro gives me

```
f {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query:    function…}
$promise: Object
 >catch:function(callback){
 >finally:function(callback){
 >then:function(callback,errback,progressback){
 >_proto_:object
 $resolved: true
 proficiency: 2
 >profs:object
 >_proto_:Resource
```

---

I'm unable to call the value of pro which is "2". This is what i tried in my controller

```
$scope.getPro = function () {
        $scope.pro = proService.getValue($scope.userId, $scope.snapshotId).then(function(data) {
             $scope.rating = data.pro;
             console.log($scope.rating);
             });
        };
```

---

Please help me with what i'm doing wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your controller code to deal with the promise that is returned from your service. Try this:

```
$scope.getProficiency = function () {
        proficiencyService.getValue({userId: $scope.userId, courseKey: $scope.courseKey, activityId: $scope.activityId}).
    then(function(proficiencyValue) {
        $scope.proficiency = proficiencyValue;
        $scope.proficiency.rating = 5 * Math.round(($scope.proficiency.proficiency * 10)/5);
        console.log($scope.proficiency);
    });
};
```